# Enabling SSLv3 support for PHP 5.4.4 SoapClient

Tags: php, soap-client

With this code:

`$soap = new SoapClient('https://test-api.geotrust.com/webtrust/query.jws?WSDL');`

I am seeing this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://test-api.geotrust.com/webtrust/query.jws?WSDL' : failed to load external entity "https://test-api.geotrust.com/webtrust/query.jws?WSDL"

If you have PHP 5.5, you can do this:

```
$soap = new SoapClient($url),
array (
"ssl_method" => "SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv23"
)
```

Any such solution for PHP 5.4.4? I cannot upgrade PHP at this time.

I've already tried the `sslv3://` suggestion I found online, but it doesn't work on Debian.

Thanks.

Comment: What is TLSv3? Is that SSLv3 or TLS 1.3?

Answer (score 0):

> SoapClient::SoapClient(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

It sounds like you **don't** have an SSL/TLS server listening. You can reproduce it with the following. Note the use of port 80 rather than 443.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect stackoverflow.com:80
CONNECTED(00000003)
140735323054556:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:787:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 320 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

---

If you **do** have an SSL/TLS server listening, then you can try to connect to it using a single protocol:

**SSL v3**:

```
openssl s_client -ssl3 -connect example.com:443
```

**TLS 1.0**:

```
openssl s_client -tls1 -connect example.com:443 -servername example.com
```

**TLS 1.1**:

```
openssl s_client -tls1_1 -connect example.com:443 -servername example.com
```

**TLS 1.2**:

```
openssl s_client -tls1_2 -connect example.com:443 -servername example.com
```

---

> ```
> array (
>   "ssl_method" => "SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv23"
> )
> ```

Just bike shedding, but in C we usually use the 2/3 method and then disable useless protocols and options. For example:

```
const SSL_METHOD* method = SSLv23_method();
if(method == NULL) handleFailure();

SSL_CTX* ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
if(ctx == NULL) handleFailure();

/* Cannot fail ??? */
const long flags = SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION;
SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, flags);
```

In the code above, we use the 2/3 method, and then we disable SSLv2 (broken), SSLv3 (weak/wounded) and Compression (broken, leaks information). That means we use TLS 1.0 and above for the connection. If TLS 1.2 is available, then its used; else if TLS 1.1 is available, then its used; else TLS 1.0 is used.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed post, but I was hoping the title would make it clear I was looking for TLSv3 support in PHP 5.4.4. PHP 5.5 supports SSLv3, but the older versions do not.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant SSLV3, not TLS.

Comment: Sorry @taco. I'm not sure what PHP 5.x supports. I answered based on the question's OpenSSL tag. But are you certain you have an SSL/TLS server listening? The other thing I've seen cause weird errors is mixing/matching OpenSSL version like 0.9.8 and 1.0.1. They are *not* binary compatible.